# How to detect SMS messages in "Ionic Capacitor" without using the code "getAppHash()" of the sms retriever

Tags: android, ionic-framework, frameworks, ionic4, capacitor

I am working with "`Ionic capacitor`", I need to receive the SMS message coming from a server with a validation code. I only found the "`sms-retriever`" plugin but it only works by sending the code that generates `this.smsRetriever.getAppHas();` Does anyone know another way to detect the arrival of SMS messages?

Comment: Did you find solution for this?